# how to remove attribute from link using jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have a link that looks like this:

```
<a onclick="myLightbox" rel="lightbox" href="image.jpg" title="">
```

I am trying `$element.prop("onclick", null);` to remove the attributes `onclick` and `rel`, but just don't know how to make it work

Can anyone please help me? The a tag does not have an id, and I just can't make it have one as that link is generated by a CMS i do not have control over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```
   $("a[href*='image.jpg']").removeAttr("rel");
```

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/eFqsG/3/

Answer (score 1):

Use [removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

Comment: removeAttr is good but it does not work in IE 6 ,7 and 8 add so using prop is better to avoid issues.

Comment: Isn't jquery compatible with IE 6+ according to http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

- `rel` is not  a property but an attribute. Use `.removeAttr('rel')`
- For onclick, see [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).

Answer (score 0):

Put an id or class for jquery selection or you can also select with tag like this

```
$('a').prop("onclick",null);
```

You must provide selector as $element is not recognized here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function(index, a) {
    var a = $(a);
    if(a.attr('rel') == 'lightbox' && a.attr('onclick') == 'myLightbox') {
        a.attr('rel', null).attr('onclick', null);
    }
});
```